# Send iOS push notification from PHP

Tags: php, ios, notifications

I'm working on an iOS app that use iOS Push Notifications. I want to send the notification from a php script on my server. The code in my app works really good for registering for remote notification and receive them. I use this php script to send notification and it works well too:

```
<?php

// My device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// My private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'myPrivateKey';

// My alert message here:
$message = 'New Push Notification!';

//badge
$badge = 1;

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'badge' => $badge,
    'sound' => 'newMessage.wav'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Error, notification not sent' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'notification sent!' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

My problem is that if i run this script by terminal on my imac, all works good and notifications are sent, but if i upload it on my server it doesn't work. My certificate is valid and it's in the same folder of the script. When i try to run the script on the server, i add this line to include the certificate file and use the variable $cerificate:

```
$certificate = file_get_contents('ck.pem');
```

This is the error of the php server side:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in script.php on line 29
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out
```

Why this happens? Do i have to add something on my server to enable pans connection?

-----UPDATE QUESTION-----

My first problem was that i didn't have the privileges to send connection on port 2195 and receive response on port 2196. Now, my server admin enabled these connection and i have different errors:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in script.php on line 28

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in script.php on line 28

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in script.php on line 28
```

Failed to connect: 0

Comment: can you make a telnet connection from your server to APNS server (from servers console)?

Comment: Some time server won't allow you to use port which is required... better ask your server admin and confirm if you got privileges... are you using shared hosting...? this happens in shared hosting...

Comment: Yes, i'm using shared hosting and i have just write to my server admin.
@rokjarc sorry but i'm not able to test a telnet connection because don't know how can i do that, sorry but i'm a new programmer :(

Comment: if you have access to servers console (not sure if you do) you could type in `telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195` and observe the response

Comment: No, i don't think to have access to it. I can access to the database, control panel or FTP

Comment: I updated my question after enable my privileges on the ports

Comment: Hi, I used your code to send push to ios. It is working fine, only one problem, How do we know if the notification is not sent as the `$result` contains an integer in every case, either, success or failure. I have passed a random digit as token and it returns integer like 115 or 65 and it changes, every time. So `!$result` wont work. How do we achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens when you are using shared hosting, and hosting provider don't give you privileges to use outbound connections on port 2195 and 2196. You should use VPS or use some other providers like urbanAirship and parse.com for this. Or even you can run your own local server... for that

Comment: Ok, i use shared hosting so this is my problem. Can't my server admin give me the privileges to use these ports? And what happens if i change the port number when i try to make the connection?

Comment: You will need these ports as APNS services will communicate on these ports 2195 to send and 2196 for feedback service, but firewall block them usually. You must consult your hosting provider for this.

Comment: I updated my question after enable my privileges on the ports

Comment: Also check the path of .pem

Comment: My certificate is valid, because i can send notification from my pc, executing the php script, right? on the server, my pem file is in the same directory of the php script and if i echo the certificate, i can see it on the browser. So it is set right no? I didn't understand how can i use allow_self_signed and verify_peer, where should i use them?

Comment: Ok, i added these lines but nothing is changed.
stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "allow_self_signed", true);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "verify_peer", false);

Comment: Error comes while executing `fwrite` did you check your php script in local server? is this only coming in live server? and working fine in local server?

Comment: in local server all works good, also with allow_self_signed and verify_peer options. error is not on fwrite, but it's here 

($fp = stream_socket_client(
 'sslv2://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
 $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);)

Comment: I think firewall not allowing handshake . As 2196 will be for feedback... Admin log can help us more...

Comment: One thing remove this and see STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, may be firewall or server don't allow to create persistent server...

Comment: I removed this too but nothing changed :(

Comment: if i change this 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195' to this 'sslv2://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195' my first error changes: Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: failed to create an SSL handle in script.php on line 30

Comment: ok now all works good! My problem was this, i replace this: 
$certificate = file_get_contents('/path/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certificate);
with this:
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
The certificate must be in the same directory of the php script and file_get_contents can't be used. Thanks for the help!